# Unable to login after installing MySQL database using bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, centos

I have connected to a remote CentOS machine in SSH and ran the below script to install a MySQL database there:

```
# install and start mysql
yum -y install mysql-server
service mysqld start

# setup some random passwords
USER_PASS=`openssl rand -base64 8`
ROOT_PASS=`openssl rand -base64 12`

# create an SQL file to be executed for 
# changing root password, setting up new user, create new database etc.

echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$ROOT_PASS') WHERE User='root';" > /tmp/init.sql
echo "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';" >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "DROP DATABASE test;"  >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%';" >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "CREATE DATABASE testdb;" >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "CREATE USER 'testusr'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '$USER_PASS';"  >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "CREATE USER 'testusr'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$USER_PASS';" >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testusr'@'127.0.0.1';" >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testusr'@'localhost';" >> /tmp/init.sql
echo "flush privileges;" >> /tmp/init.sql

# execute the SQL file from root user
cat /tmp/init.sql | mysql -u root
```

After this, whenever I try to login locally using the `testusr` user I created above, I get Access Denied message. However the root login (using the newly set root password) seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get ? Check if the access is denied to either `testusr@localhost` or `testusr@127.0.0.1`. You can try to use the wildcard `%` as host.

Comment: I tried something like this: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'testusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$USER_PASS'; --- and it did not work

Comment: Let me try using the wildcard `%` for the host...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access was being denied to `testusr@localhost`. As hinted by @Martin above, using the wildcard `%` as host solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use mysqladmin for creating user (Since its CentOS)

`mysqladmin -uroot Password rootpwd`

`mysqladmin -utest Password testpwd`

This will create users for you

Later can take care of grant previldeges